# Ubuntu 20.04: problem with connection of external HDD to a router

Tags: external-hdd, 20.04, router

I connected an external Hard Disk Drive via USB port to a "Vodafone Station Revolution" router to share it between two computers.
On the first machine that mounts Ubuntu 16.04 the HDD works perfectly: just type `smb://vodafone.station` in Nautilus window "connect to the server".
Instead on the other PC that mounts the new Ubuntu 20.04, I'm returned the error "Unable to access the location; recovery of the list of shares from the server failed: connection interrupted due to a software problem".
I don't know what to do...

Comment: Have you opened ports in your firewall, and have you edited /etc/samba/smbusers?

Comment: I didn't edited /etc/samba/smbusers in neither case, but Ubuntu 16.04 works correctly, not Ubuntu 20.04